# How I can use multiple rows in one recyclerView (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I want to use differnt rows in my app which users based on Firestore Database. So i want categorize users by point number rating (Long). So there will be multiple ranks with rating numbers. For example, if rating is 100 i want to show red row with lady rank. How can i do that? Thanks for everyone)

[Here is my app screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqmgV.jpg)

My Activity Codes

```
private fun get_information() {
        database.collection("ProfPic").orderBy("Username",
            Query.Direction.DESCENDING).addSnapshotListener { snaphot, exception ->
            if (exception != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, exception.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                if (snaphot != null) {
                    if (!snaphot.isEmpty) {
                        val documents = snaphot.documents
                        posts_list.clear()
                        for (document in documents) {
                            val username = document.get("Username") as String
                            val fullname = document.get("Fullname") as String
                            val rank = document.get("Rank") as String
                            val rating = document.get("Rating") as Long



                            val download_post = publiks(username, fullname, rating, rank)
                            posts_list.add(download_post)
                        }
                    }
                    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

My Adapter Codes

```
class new_adapter(var post_list: List<publiks>, clickListener: Feed) : RecyclerView.Adapter<new_adapter.PostHolder>() {

    private var clickListener: Feed = clickListener;




    class PostHolder(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {



        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {


            }
        }

    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PostHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rec_row, parent, false)
        return PostHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostHolder, position: Int) {
        var userModel = post_list.get(position)


        holder.itemView.username.text = post_list[position].username
        holder.itemView.fullname.text = post_list[position].fullname
        holder.itemView.rating.text = post_list[position].rating.toString()
        holder.itemView.idrank.text = post_list[position].rank
```

}

Comment: [do not post photos of your code, paste the code directly please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Sir i want to show firestore data in recyclerview with points in specific rows (red, green, etc) But i see one user located in all rows

Answer (score 1):

you can write this code in onBindViewHolder function

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostHolder, position: Int) {
    var userModel = post_list.get(position)

    if (userModel.rating == 100) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black)
    }

    holder.itemView.username.text = userModel.username
    holder.itemView.fullname.text = userModel.fullname
    holder.itemView.rating.text = userModel.rating.toString()
    holder.itemView.idrank.text = userModel.rank
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for response. But it didn't worked

Comment: Could you research viewType in recylclerView. Maybe this will solve your problem.